# DOM with javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new with javascript/jquery. I'm trying to retrieve some values from a div, without success. This is what I get in the execution of my code.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: getQuestionOptionValues is not defined.
```

My code:

```
<div class="section row" id="divQ1113">
    <div class="section row principal_question">
        <label>Escoja una opción</label>    
    </div>
    <div class="section row sub_question"></div>
    <div class="section row">
        <select name="Q1113" id="Q1113">
            <option value="">Opciones</option>
            <option value="Q1113_QO3514">SI</option>
            <option value="Q1113_QO3515">NO</option>
        </select>    
    </div>
</div>
```

This is a dropdownlist and I only want to retrieve the selected value, but only a part of the value. In this case 3514 or 3515.

And I'm trying this:

```
var ret = getQuestionOptionValues("div#divQ<?php echo $cond->question_id_dep;   ?>");
```

The result of this is:

```
var ret = getQuestionOptionValues("div#divQ1113");
```

And the function does the next:

```
function getQuestionOptionValues(element) {
    var ret = new Array();
    x$(element).find("input").filter(function() {
        return this.selected;
    }).each(function(optelement, index, xui) {
        ret.push(parseInt(x$(optelement).attr("value").toString().replace(/Q\d+_QO/g, "")));
    });
    return ret;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

I've to do the same for another kind of div, with checkboxes. Like this:

```
<div class="section row" id="divQ2" style="display: none;">
    <div class="section row principal_question">
        <label>Por favor indique el motivo o motivos de su insatisfacción:</label>
    </div>
    <div class="section row">
        <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="Q2_QO1" id="Q2_QO1" />Limpieza habitación</label>
    </div>
    <div class="section row">
        <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="Q2_QO2" id="Q2_QO2" />Atención del personal</label>
    </div>
    <div class="section row">
        <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="Q2_QO3" id="Q2_QO3" />Restaurante, alimentación, calidad o falta de servicio</label>
    </div>
    <div class="section row">
        <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="Q2_QO4" id="Q2_QO4" />Estado de las instalaciones</label>
    </div>
    <div class="section row">
        <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="Q2_QO5" id="Q2_QO5" />Otros motivos, especificar</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

And in this case I've to retrieve only the checked checkboxes, specifically the last number on name or id label. I.E. For Q2_QO5, I need to get 5, but only if the checkbox is checked.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You'll find you will get much quicker and better answers if you take the time to format your code to a readable state. I've edited your code for you here.

Comment: looks like an issue with scope of `getQuestionOptionValues`... whether `getQuestionOptionValues` is defined in another function...

Comment: And what is the x$ ? Some kind of conflict version of jQuery?

Comment: Make sure you define `getQuestionOptionValues` before calling it

Comment: Hi Gal, Where and How have I to define getQuestionOptionValues?

Answer (score 0):

Notice:Browser reads your code in this way: left to right and top to bottom. So, If you didn't define `getQuestionOptionValues` this it will display the `undefined` error. If this function is into an another script file, make sure that you call it before all other script, to avoid this error. :)

Answer (score 0):

In your code i have got some doubts about x$() is there any function with name x$() you are using is understood from code, also how getQuestionOptionValues() method is invoked is also make confusions. due to those confusions i rewrite your code to this. First you try this completely then try to make change on your code. Please run the code snippet given at the end. I think this will help you.

### part1 script

```
 <script>
        /*
           instead of this you can use your code. that is
           var id='<?php echo $cond->question_id_dep;?>';
        */
        var id='1113'; 

        $("div#divQ"+id+" select").change(function(){
           var ret = getQuestionOptionValues("div#divQ"+id);
           alert('Selected option value is ' + ret);
        });

        var ret = getQuestionOptionValues("div#divQ"+id);
        alert('Selected option value is ' + ret);

        function getQuestionOptionValues(element) {
            return $(element+" select").val().split("_")[1].replace("QO","");
        }

        $("#divQ2 .checkbox input").click(function(){
            var ret = getCheckedCheckboxes();
            alert('checked checkboxes ' + ret);
        });

        function getCheckedCheckboxes(){
            var ar = Array();
            $("#divQ2 .checkbox input:checked").each(function(){
                ar.push($(this).attr('id').split("_")[1].replace("QO",""));
            });
            return ar;
        }

        alert('checked checkboxes ' + getCheckedCheckboxes());

</script>
```

### part2 script

```
<script>
       $("#divQ2 .checkbox input").click(function(){
            var ret = getCheckedCheckboxes();
            alert('checked checkboxes ' + ret);
        });

        function getCheckedCheckboxes(){
            var ar = Array();
            $("#divQ2 .checkbox input:checked").each(function(){
                ar.push($(this).attr('id').split("_")[1].replace("QO",""));
            });
            return ar;
        }

        alert('checked checkboxes ' + getCheckedCheckboxes());

 </script>
```

### Code snippet below

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>


In your code i have some doubts about x$() you are using 
so i have rewrite your code something like this. can you please try 
this.

  <div class="section row" id="divQ1113">
   <div class="section row principal_question">
    <label>Escoja una opción</label>    
   </div>
   <div class="section row sub_question"></div>
   <div class="section row">
    <select name="Q1113" id="Q1113">
     <option value="123">Opciones</option>
     <option selected value="Q1113_QO3514">SI</option>
     <option value="Q1113_QO3515">NO</option>
    </select>    
   </div>
  </div>

For second part of your question you can use like this
  
 <div class="section row" id="divQ2" style="">
    <div class="section row principal_question">
        <label>Por favor indique el motivo o motivos de su insatisfacción:</label>
    </div>
    <div class="section row">
        <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" checked value="1" name="Q2_QO1" id="Q2_QO1" />Limpieza habitación</label>
    </div>
    <div class="section row">
        <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="Q2_QO2" id="Q2_QO2" />Atención del personal</label>
    </div>
    <div class="section row">
        <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="Q2_QO3" id="Q2_QO3" />Restaurante, alimentación, calidad o falta de servicio</label>
    </div>
    <div class="section row">
        <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="Q2_QO4" id="Q2_QO4" />Estado de las instalaciones</label>
    </div>
    <div class="section row">
        <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="Q2_QO5" id="Q2_QO5" />Otros motivos, especificar</label>
    </div>
</div>
 
  
  

  <script>
   /*
      instead of this you can use your code. that is
      var id='<?php echo $cond->question_id_dep;?>';
   */
   var id='1113'; 

   $("div#divQ"+id+" select").change(function(){
      var ret = getQuestionOptionValues("div#divQ"+id);
      alert('Selected option value is ' + ret);
   });

   var ret = getQuestionOptionValues("div#divQ"+id);
   alert('Selected option value is ' + ret);

   function getQuestionOptionValues(element) {
    return $(element+" select").val().split("_")[1].replace("QO","");
   }
   
   $("#divQ2 .checkbox input").click(function(){
    var ret = getCheckedCheckboxes();
    alert('checked checkboxes ' + ret);
   });
   
   function getCheckedCheckboxes(){
    var ar = Array();
    $("#divQ2 .checkbox input:checked").each(function(){
     ar.push($(this).attr('id').split("_")[1].replace("QO",""));
    });
    return ar;
   }
   
   alert('checked checkboxes ' + getCheckedCheckboxes());

  </script>
```

Comment: You have a lot of inline script. All of the above needs to live in a load event or at the bottom of the page. Why do you have all these alerts between the assigns and why not reuse the functions you wrote?

Comment: @mplungjan  sorry i only aim it to make it  understandable by a javascript beginner. I will try to change. Thank you for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

This is simpler

Given

```
var ret = getQuestionOptionValues("div#divQ<?php echo $cond->question_id_dep;   ?>");
```

you can do

```
function getQuestionOptionValues(selString) {
  var opt = $(selString+" select").val();
  return opt?parseInt(opt.split("QO")[1],10):"";
}
```

to be defined AFTER loading jQuery and executed AFTER the divs are loaded

Example:

```js
    function getQuestionOptionValues(selString) {
      var opt = $(selString+" select").val();
      return opt?parseInt(opt.split("QO")[1],10):"";
    }
    $(function() {
      window.console&&console.log(getQuestionOptionValues("div#divQ1113"));
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="section row" id="divQ1113">
    <div class="section row principal_question">
        <label>Escoja una opción</label>    
    </div>
    <div class="section row sub_question"></div>
    <div class="section row">
        <select name="Q1113" id="Q1113">
            <option value="">Opciones</option>
            <option selected value="Q1113_QO3514">SI</option>
            <option value="Q1113_QO3515">NO</option>
        </select>    
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks to me like one of the following:

- You have a typo somewhere referencing the function by the wrong name
- If the code calling the function and the function is in separate files, are they loaded in the appropriate order, i.e the script with the function is loaded before the code using it?

A possible third explanation that probably isn't very likely unless the actual code is very different from the snippets here, is that you are wrapping code with functions to manipulate scope.

I've created a jsfiddle with a slightly modified version of your code here:
https://jsfiddle.net/thedole/n10yxmsd/7/

```
var select = document.querySelector('#Q1113');
select.addEventListener('change', function(e){
    var ret = getQuestionOptionValues("div#divQ1113");
    alert(ret);
});

function getQuestionOptionValues(element) {
    var ret = [];
    $(element)
        .find("option")
        .filter(":selected")
        .each(function(){
           ret.push(parseInt($(this).attr("value").toString().replace(/Q\d+_QO/g,"")));
        });
    return ret;
}
```

I'm not familiar with the xui library and I don't think jsfiddle has support for it, so I'm using jquery instead but I suspect they behave very similarly.

Here is Douglas Crockfords take on script tags:
http://javascript.crockford.com/script.html where especially the following section is relevant:

> If a script is defining functions or data that are used by other
>   functions, then the defining must be done before use. So the defining
>   scripts must come before the using scripts.